# How to use inplace const char* as std::string content

Tags: c++, string, flash, c++11

I am working on a embedded SW project. A lot of strings are stored inside flash memory. I would use these strings (usually `const char*` or `const wchar*`) as `std::string`'s data. That means I want to avoid creating a copy of the original data because of memory restrictions.

An extended use might be to read the flash data via stringstream directly out of the flash memory.

Example which unfortunately is not working in place:

```
const char* flash_adr = 0x00300000;
size_t length = 3000;
std::string str(flash_adr, length);
```

Any ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: You cannot avoid that `std::string` copies that data actually. Can you access the flash memory as text segment data?

Comment: On some platforms this might be the case. Could it help?

Comment: You could provide symbols for them with a linker script then at fixed addresses and with a fixed preserved size. Sticking as `const char*` of course.

Comment: Tale a look at [`std::string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view).

Comment: @BerndL. No, you're right about that, but how addresses are interpreted as type (e.g. `const char*`) is still up to you (like you did with `const char* flash_adr = 0x00300000;`). Why do you actually need these to be handled as `std::string`?

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ For example to use a stringstream to read out of it. There are several libs available for c++ stream for json, xml, ...

Comment: @BerndL. Maybe you could provide your own implementation of `std::istream` based on `const char*` rather than `std::string`.

Comment: @Captain you mean `std::experimental::string_view`, of course.

Comment: Why do you need the data as `std::string`? Do you need it to be handed over to other functions as `std::string`? Or is your real use case an `istream`? In the latter case, you might want to look at boost::iostream, basic_array_source

Comment: Both is useful. Boost is not an option because of its dependencies its difficult to use only parts and many embedded compiler have issues with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now used string_span described in CPP Core Guidelines (https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md). GSL provides a complete implementation (GSL: Guidelines Support Library https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL).

If you know the address of your string inside flash memory you can just use the address directly with the following constructor to create a string_span.

```
 constexpr basic_string_span(pointer ptr, size_type length) noexcept
    : span_(ptr, length)
{}
```

std::string_view might have done the same job as Captain Obvlious (https://stackoverflow.com/users/845568/captain-obvlious) commented as my favourite comment.

I am quite happy with the solution. It works good from performance side including providing a good readability.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to go with compiler and library specific implementations, here is an example that works in MSVC 2013.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string str("A std::string with a larger length than yours");
    char *flash_adr = "Your source from the flash";
    char *reset_adr = str._Bx._Ptr; // Keep the old address around

    // Change the inner buffer
    (char*)str._Bx._Ptr = flash_adr;

    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    // Reset the pointer or the program will crash
    (char*)str._Bx._Ptr = reset_adr;

    return 0;
}
```

It will print `Your source from the flash`.

The idea is to reserve a std::string capable of fitting the strings in your flash and keep on changing its inner buffer pointer.

You need to customize this for your compiler and as always, you need to be very very careful.

Comment: "C makes it easy to shoot yourself in the foot; C++ makes it harder, but when you do it blows your whole leg off." -- Bjarne Stroustrup

Comment: Since `operator<<()` for `std::string` sends characters from range [`str.begin()`, `str.end()`) to the stream, I'd say your result is pure luck.

Comment: This is just a hack and because platform dependent and unsafe we will never use such kind of solution.